# AMD gpu pro driver error

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have AMD Radeon HD 8670M and Intel HD 4400 hybrid graphics and ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried to install the amd gpu pro driver by following the instructions, but ubuntu didn't start after installation. It rather showed a black screen instead of the login screen.
When I tried entering "lspci -k" in recovery mode, it showed "kernel driver in use: radeon, amdgpu" under the gpu card info. Does that mean there is a confliction between the radeon opensource driver and amdgpu? Do I have to remove the radeon opensource driver first to install amdgpu?

Comment: Your card isn't supported by AMDGPU-PRO: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: Black screen FAQ is here if you haven't already looked. http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/647604

Comment: But when I chose my card on amd website,  it directed me to the AMDGPU-PRO